# How edit elements of existing link and open the edited version of the link? (Without saving it localy)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to build a html website_A where you can type some data and then open another website_B with a button click and this website_B would be changed according to the text we typed in the first website.

For example we have a website_B example.com with a
`<h1 id="xxx">`

We save the link in our website_A as a string, insert an input field and button with onClick function:

```
<input type="text" id="text_id" name="text_name"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Open Link!" onclick="openLink()">

<script>
   var link = 'example.com';
   function openLink() {
   link.getElementById("xxx").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text_id").text;
   window.open(link);
</script>
}
```

It should open the link with the changed h1.

Somehow it doesn't work, I don't know the javascript much, not even sure if I can achieve it with js or I have to use some othere languages. I googled a lot and didn't find anything, most information is about changing files locally or changing just the href link, not its elements.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can save the content of the <h1> of the website _A/index.html inside the localStorage, and then export the content from the website _A/anotherFile.html

Comment: Passing the data from one domain to another requires other technologies, I don't think that you can achieve this using JavaScript only, it only works if the website accepts inside their URL queries, for example, inside their website URL, they have 
 ?TheH1Content=<here you put you h1 content>,

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is, the website_B is not maintained by me. But the elements of website_B do have IDs and you can write your text manually, even save a quicklink of the website as your pattern and open it later in edited form. I tried to save it locally, but since the website_B is confidential, it's not allowed to save the files of the website locally and open it like this (I get some sort of security error).